# Google Maps Toggle between marker groups

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a JSON feed that includes coordinates and info about the type of business to be listed on a Google Maps canvas. In the JSON feed, the industry field is represented by integers, and can be 1, 2 or both. A less abstract way to present this is that a business can be either a restaurant, retail or both.

I managed the get the toggle working between these 2 types by checking whether the initial array value is equal to first type array value, I but can't figure out how to handle a situation where a business is both. I have searched for "in" operator in Javascript that can check the presence of a value in array and return true or false but not able to find anything useful.

http://jsfiddle.net/serkanh/BVjGh/16/

Current way of checking the type of business:

```
for(i=0; i < markers.length; i++){                     
    if(markers[i].category === category){                 
           markers[i].setVisible(true);            
    }else{                 
           markers[i].setVisible(false);            
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your values are 1 and 2, it should be pretty easy: set the value for both types to 3. And test with

```
if(markers[i].category&3) {
  // Both
} else if(markers[i].category&2) {
  // type 2
} else if(markers[i].category&1) {
  // type 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What i ended up doing is based on your answer but slightly different. I ended up using reduce funtion for the industry(category) array so if value is 1, 2 or total 3 which means both industries.Here is the final version if anyone intersted.http://jsfiddle.net/serkanh/f93Qv/2/